# Grunt.js: Replace path when concat multiple CSS files from different directories

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I'm trying to minify and combine multiple CSS files using Grunt.js concat and cssmin from different directories.
Unfortunately, css breaks since each CSS has relative link to resources, for example:

```
background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
```

I was trying to find an answer for that on the web, but without any luck. Here is an example from Gruntfile.js code, which combine 2 different WP plugins CSS files:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        iphorm_woocommerce: {
            src: [
                '../wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder/css/styles.css',
                '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/select2.css',
                '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css',
                '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css',
                '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css',
            ],
            dest: '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/combined.css'
        }
    }
    })
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
cssmin : {
            options: {
                rebase: true,
                relativeTo: './'
            },
            target : {
                src : <your sources>,
                dest : "dest directory"
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1, Mar 2023: the GitHub repo for cssmin only documents 2 options (sourceMap and report).  The rebase options are not mentioned but work perfectly. What's with the node community?....